# Have a htaccess issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a server in which multiple website is hosting. one is primary and rest all is secondary the primary code is on the root which have its own .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
  RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

RewriteBase /

and all the secondary domian runes by .htaccess rule

if i put (^$ app/webroot/    [L] && (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]) these on htaccess my primary domain works fine. and all the rest goes to internal server error.

if i have remove (^$ app/webroot/    [L] && (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]) this from htaccess all the secondary domains work fine but primary get an 500 error

please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Why not simply: put "secondary domain" in `app/webroot`

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/folder1/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/folder2/"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
```

For each folder you want to bypass, add a RewriteCond line, and end all but the final RewriteCond with [OR]. Note that the [L] in the rewrite rule tells it to stop there and bypass the rest of the rewrite rules.

Comment: RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L] #####
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]

I just want to add this rule for (www.example.com) and for rest all add 

 RewriteBase /